# Is it possible to hide one div and show another div after scrolling 50% or more?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have one section inside 2 DIV's where the div's name 1st div and 2nd div . By Default 2nd div will be hidden, after scrolling 50% or more 1st div will be hidden and 2nd div will be displayed. How do i do that?

I used:

```
var heightDivid = $(window).height() / 2;
$(window).on('scroll', function(e){
    $('.sections-class').each(function(){
        if(this.getBoundingClientRect().top <= heightDivid ){
             $(this).removeClass('heightDivids') ;
        }
        else{
             $(this).addClass('heightDivids') ;
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: create a fiddle of your scenario and will be able to help you

Comment: Please show existing code. This site is not intended for us to make your project for you. There are many javascript ways to do this, but without something to elaborate on we are basically just writing all of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can alter something along these lines to do what you're attempting to do.

Utilize jQuery's `scrollTop` to identify where you want the change to occur.

Set a limit for when you want to hide the `one` div and show the `two` div.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var height = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(height  >  10) {
        $('.two').show();
        $('.one').hide();
    }
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/xv2m4qn6/

If you want the effect to reverse simply add a second conditional:

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/xv2m4qn6/1/

Answer (score -1):

At Last I did :) and it's work for me .... Thank you all for your help :)

```
 var shadowEdgePoint = $(window).height() / 2;
    $(window).on('scroll', function(e){
        $('.section-class').each(function(){
            if(this.getBoundingClientRect().top <= shadowEdgePoint){
                         $('.two').show();
                        $('.one').hide();
            }
                else{
                        $('.two').hide();
                        $('.one').show();
                    }
        })
    });
```